# hive1.2.1 create table failed MetaException

Tags: hadoop, hive

when i create a table in my CLI,here i get some message like follow,help!

```
hive> create table a (x int);
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:For direct MetaStore DB connections, we don't support retries at the client level.)
```

what should i do?

here is my version message:
 hive version is 1.2.1
 mac 10.10.3
 hadoop 2.6.0

---

2015-07-17 10:39:37,384 ERROR [main]: exec.DDLTask (DDLTask.java:failed(520)) - org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:For direct MetaStore DB connections, we don't support retries at the client level.)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:720)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:4135)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:306)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:160)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:88)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1653)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1412)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1195)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1059)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1049)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:213)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:165)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:376)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:736)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:681)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:621)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: MetaException(message:For direct MetaStore DB connections, we don't support retries at the client level.)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.reconnect(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:308)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:148)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.createTable(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:714)
        ... 21 more

2015-07-17 10:39:37,385 ERROR [main]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printError(960)) - FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:For direct MetaStore DB connections, we don't support retries at the client level.)
2015-07-17 10:39:37,385 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogEnd(148)) - 
2015-07-17 10:39:37,386 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogBegin(121)) - 
2015-07-17 10:39:37,386 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogEnd(148)) - 
2015-07-17 10:39:37,388 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogBegin(121)) - 
2015-07-17 10:39:37,388 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogEnd(148)) -

Comment: Have a look at the Hive log files and expand the question with what you find.

Comment: my hive.log  file is  below there,since i run some commad like: schematool -dbType mysql -initSchema  ,i can create table! i mean woo!!,but i still do not understand why? and before this time , i do not run this command

Comment: @wangchunli  Is this still an issue or is it fixed?